# How to get project_id in newer Google Cloud Function runtimes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

With Google Cloud Functions `python39` runtime `os.environ['GCP_PROJECT']` in  Google Cloud Function gives `KeyError: 'GCP_PROJECT'` error. [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#newer_runtimes) states:

> Newer runtimes automatically set fewer environment variables than
> older ones.

My question: is there other way than:

- setting is through env var at deployment time
- using [the metadata server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088076/trying-to-find-the-current-project-id-of-the-deployed-python-function-in-google/65099801#65099801)

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65099801/13130697

Comment: Thank you @Dharmaraj for the link ! In deed this is a solution but I was hoping for simpler one (less code, less dependencies)